# Drupal Page loading... what exactly is on page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Is there some sort of Module or something that I can set for only Administrators to show on a page, when it loads (like at the bottom or something) that tells me ALL CONTENT that gets loaded or something on that page?  Like, I need Nodes, Modules, Taxonomy Terms, Templates, Views, URL Aliases, etc. etc. etc., EVERYTHING POSSIBLE.

Problem I'm having is that I didn't create this site I am now managing with the Drupal CMS, however, Drupal has so much damn content areas all over the place that it's literally impossible to track where the hell something is happening at.  There is a Views Module, Blocks, etc. etc. on a page, but I need to find out all Drupal related content on a page somehow after it loads it should spit out everything that is related to Drupal that gets loaded on that page.  The people that put the site together to begin with are uncooperative about helping with this, even as they are getting paid money to do site edits, they do not share any knowledge of what they do exactly!  In my opinion, they are useless!

So, looking at the View for that page, it looks like it is outputting only the "ALL VIDEOS" section.  Where should I be looking at to find out how they are being sorted in the years sections of that page?

Ok, so I see in the main.js file this bit of code:

```
  /* Isotope for Videos and Gallery */
  blam('#block-views-videos-block .view-content').isotope({itemSelector: '.views-row', animationEngine: 'jquery'});
  blam('#block-views-press-gallery-block .view-content').isotope({itemSelector: '.views-row', animationEngine: 'jquery'});

  /* Remove class 'active' from video menu items */
  removeActiveClass('.menu-name-menu-videos-menu ul li', 1);

  blam('.menu-name-menu-videos-menu ul li a').click(function(){
    var selector;
    var menu_item = blam(this).text();
    removeActiveClass('.menu-name-menu-videos-menu ul li', 0);
    /*Add 'active' class to video menu item*/
    blam(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

    if( menu_item.indexOf("2012") != -1 ) {
      selector = '.2012';
    } else if( menu_item.indexOf("2011") != -1 ) {
      selector = '.2011';
    } else if( menu_item.indexOf("2010") != -1 ) {
      selector = '.2010';
    } else if( menu_item.indexOf("2009") != -1 ) {
      selector = '.2009';
    } else if( menu_item.indexOf("2008") != -1 ) {
      selector = '.2008';
    } else if( menu_item.indexOf("2007") != -1) {
      selector = '.2007';
    }

    if(selector) {
      blam('#block-views-videos-block .view-content').isotope({filter: selector});
    } else {
      blam('#block-views-videos-block .view-content').isotope({filter: '.views-row'});
    }
    return false;
  });

});

/* Removes all Active classes from menu items */

function removeActiveClass(e, i){
  var elements = blam(e);

  for(var index = i; index < elements.length; index++) {
    blam(elements[index]).removeClass('active');
  }
}
```

And so, I changed this bit here:

```
    if( menu_item.indexOf("2012") != -1 ) {
      selector = '.2012';
    } else if( menu_item.indexOf("2011") != -1 ) {
      selector = '.2011';
    } else if( menu_item.indexOf("2010") != -1 ) {
      selector = '.2010';
    } else if( menu_item.indexOf("2009") != -1 ) {
      selector = '.2009';
    } else if( menu_item.indexOf("2008") != -1 ) {
      selector = '.2008';
    } else if( menu_item.indexOf("2007") != -1) {
      selector = '.2007';
    }
```

To this:

```
if( menu_item.indexOf("2013") != -1 ) {
  selector = '.2013';
} else if( menu_item.indexOf("2012") != -1 ) {
  selector = '.2012';
} else if( menu_item.indexOf("2011") != -1 ) {
  selector = '.2011';
} else if( menu_item.indexOf("2010") != -1 ) {
  selector = '.2010';
} else if( menu_item.indexOf("2009") != -1 ) {
  selector = '.2009';
} else if( menu_item.indexOf("2008") != -1 ) {
  selector = '.2008';
} else if( menu_item.indexOf("2007") != -1) {
  selector = '.2007';
}
```

But it still does not work.  Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're actually outputting all videos using the Views module (it's a view called Videos I think and there's a block of that view which is what you can see here).

The filtering is actually not a Drupal thing, which is probably why you're struggling to find it.  They're using a jQuery plugin called Isotope to do the filtering which changes the opacity of items, among other things and does the animation via CSS3.  They apply a class to each item of the view, in this case each video, which has the year.  For example, any item that is from 2013 will have '2013' as a class.  I've highlighted in the attachment where I found that information from.  Using Chrome inspector (or Firebug) you can see all the Isotope classes that are added and you can see the year class too.

[image]

Now, you can see that the first three do have the class 2013, so I think this could be an issue with Isotope.  A good place to start debugging this would be to take a look at the JS file that calls the Isotope function.  I'd like to point you to the correct file but Drupal has minified the js files so it's a bit hard.

The Isotope website is here: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html

Comment: This was very helpful.  Thank you.  Now I know that the Views Isotope module is not installed on the site because it is not listed in the Modules.  But there are options for adding Contextual Filters to the view and other things... When I go to all of the views I get this for the Videos view:  `Videos
Display: Block
In database
Type: Content
default`

Comment: Perhaps they are not using the Views Isotope module, but in fact just using the Isotope js to do the filtering. You will have to hunt through the js files to find where the Isotope scripting has been done. The js files are probably listed in the themes .info file.  You can't do this via the drupal interface, you'll have to 'get your hands dirty'. The videos display: block is simply outputting the content of the view as a block. You'll see that block if you go to the blocks page from the Drupal admin dashboard.

Comment: yep, it's in the .info file:  `scripts[] = js/jquery.isotope.min.js` though not sure if there is an unminified version of this, but minified is going to be hard to deal with... arggg!

Comment: You won't have to deal with that file itself. That's the plugin and should remain unchanged. However, in another js file you should find a reference to isotope. It's there that the the developer who worked on this would 'call' isotope. Might look something like this `$('#container').isotope({ filter: '.something' });`

Comment: You are absolutely right here.  But I've included `2013` and yet it still doesn't work.  Did I miss something else?  Or did I now do this right?

Comment: I think your next port of call is to show the isotope code you're looking at. You're best option might be to place that code and a link to your videos page again in a new stack overflow question and tag it 'isotope', but I'm certainly happy to take a look if you add that code to your question as an edit.

Comment: Well, I don't see any element with a class of `2013` anywhere or even 2012, 2011, 2010 (even though these work fine)?  I don't see where that is getting put into the element, as it is written in the jQuery code...  but where is it in the DOM?

Comment: Cleared the Cache and now it works fine.  Thanks for your help on this!